# Pass value in joomla.submitbutton

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

I have made a submit button using joomla's button like this:

```
<button onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('autoresponder.transfer')">Edit</button>
```

I want to pass an 'id' along to autoresponder's transfer function from here. How can i do that?
I tried it using a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (int) $item['id']; ?>">      
      <button onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('autoresponder.transfer')">Edit</button>
```

But it is not giving me value. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

1)
instead of `<button>` you use "submit" like `<input type="submit">` .It will work and capture that hidden field with `$_POST / $_GET` .This usually works for joomla.

Before you submit the form in each handler:

```
document.getElementById("hiddenId").value = "mySpecialValue";
```

Like :

```
<input id="buttonA" type="button" value="do something" onclick="buttonA_clickHandler(event);"/>

function buttonA_clickHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenId').value = whatever;
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
}
```

2) 
To pass the value without form submit you can use link . 
like :

```
<a href="x.php?id='hiddenfieldname'">Do something </a>
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: yeaahh..but (1) it would submit the entire form..and i want only my row to be submitted (2) How would i call transfer method from that?

Comment: I have edited my answer.Please check.Edit : need to submit the form anyhow to pass the value. so make a form tag for the hidden field and the button. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the help..But again my problem is How would i call transfer method from that?

Comment: for that any how you have to use `form` .

Comment: Else you have to use link to pass the value . like `<a href="x.php?id='hiddenfieldname'">Do something </a>` I think this will solve your issue.